# Verification of LinkedList Monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, linked-list, monads, verification

I'm still learning Haskell and at the moment I'm practicing monads. Now, I defined a LinkedList monad in Haskell and implemented it, but I'm not completely sure if I'm on the right track. The reason that I'm not certain is the fact that I'm not making use of the bind or unit functions in the other functions (such as add or getFirstItem).

This is my code so far:

```
module LinkedList where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad (ap)

data LinkedList a = Success (a, LinkedList a) | Null | Fail String

instance (Show a) => Show (LinkedList a) where
    show (Success (x, previous)) = (show x) ++ " ~ " ++ (show previous)
    show (Fail s) = "An error occured " ++ s
    show Null = "END"

instance Functor LinkedList where
    fmap f (Success (x, y)) = Success (f x, fmap f y)
    fmap f Null = Null
    fmap f (Fail s) = Fail s

instance Applicative LinkedList where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad LinkedList where
    return x = Success (x, Null)
    (Success (x, xs)) >>= f = Success (getFirstItem (f x), xs >>= f)
    (Fail s) >>= f = Fail s
    Null >>= f = Null

-- Get the first element from the LinkedList
getFirstItem :: LinkedList a -> a
getFirstItem (Success (x, xs)) = x
getFirstItem Null = error "Cannot take first element of empty list"
getFirstItem (Fail s) = error (show s)

-- Get the nth element from the LinkedList
getItem :: LinkedList a -> Integer -> a
getItem (Success (x, xs)) n = if n == 0 then x else getItem xs (n - 1)
getItem (Fail s) _ = error (show s)
getItem Null _ = error "LinkedList out of bounds"

-- Add a single element to the LinkedList
add :: LinkedList a -> a -> LinkedList a
add (Success (x, xs)) y = Success (x, (add xs y))
add Null y = Success (y, Null)
add (Fail s) _ = error (show s)
```

Comment: `Fail String` should not be part of the `LinkedList a` type. It represents a failure to create a valid value, not a value itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to verify the monad laws to see if you are on the right track. Let's start with the left identity law:

```
return a >>= f = f a
```

Let's take `f` function as:

```
testFun :: Int -> LinkedList Int
testFun x = Success (x + 2, Fail "hello")
```

Let's compute `return 3 >>= testFun`:

```
return 3 = Success (3, Null)
return 3 >>= testFun = Success (5, Null)
```

Let's compute `testFun 3`:

```
testFun 3 = Success (5, Fail "hello")
```

`Success (5, Null)` is not equal to `Success (5, Fail "hello")`.

So it isn't a proper monad.

Comment: Aha, thank you! I totally forgot about the monad laws. What about my other functions? I think it would be better to let them return a LinkedList as well?

Comment: I think `Null` and `Fail String` can be converged into a single constructor. Also using `error` in the code isn't usually a good practice. Try modelling the error variant using `Maybe` or `Either`.

Comment: People often play fast and loose with the monad laws and say that the laws hold up to *some* equality, not necessarily definitional equality. I think a sensible notion of equality could simply consider all failing cases to be equal.